# Can I make some easy functions for these codes

Tags: swift, storyboard

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ortalamaLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var firstSectionCredit: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var firstSectionGrade: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    var firstNumberGrade:Double = 0 //These are my grade variables.
    var secondNumberGrade:Double = 0
    var sonuc1:Double = 0
    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let ilkKredi = Double(firstSectionCredit.text!)
        if let ilkNot = firstSectionGrade.text {
            if ilkNot == "AA" {
                firstNumberGrade = 4.0
            }
            if ilkNot == "BA" {
                firstNumberGrade = 3.5
                
            }
            if ilkNot == "BB" {
                firstNumberGrade = 3.0
            }
            if ilkNot == "CB" {
                firstNumberGrade = 2.5
            }
            if ilkNot == "CC" {
                firstNumberGrade = 2.0
            }
            if ilkNot == "DC" {
                firstNumberGrade = 1.5
            }
            if ilkNot == "DD" {
                firstNumberGrade = 1.0
            }
            if ilkNot == "FF" {
                firstNumberGrade = 0
            }
            sonuc1 = firstNumberGrade * ilkKredi!
    //I want to do these process for 8 section.I don want to rewrite all these codes.
```

I want to make university grade calculator.But it takes too much time and I repeated so much codes.I have 8 section 8 grades and 8 section credits.How can I use easy function to do that.I am beginner in Swift

Comment: You could use a `let dict = [String: Double] = ["AA": 4.0...]`

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Enums`.

```
enum Grade: String {
case AA, BA, BB, CB, CC, DC, DD, FF

var gradeValue: Double {
    switch self {
    case AA:
        return 4.0
    case BA:
        return 3.5
    case BB:
        return 3.0
    ..and so on
    }
}
}
    

if let text = firstSectionGrade.text, let textilkNot = Grade(rawValue: text) {
    firstNumberGrade = textilkNot.gradeValue
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.I didn't learn some codes yet.I have been learning Swift about 1 week

Answer (score 0):

You can condense in an `enum` all the related code

```
enum SectionGrade: String{
    case AA
    case BA
    case BB
    case CB
    case CC
    case DC
    case DD
    case FF
    
    var grade: Double{
        switch self {
        case .AA:
            return 4.0
        case .BA:
            return 3.5
        case .BB:
            return 3.0
        case .CB:
            return 2.5
        case .CC:
            return 2.0
        case .DC:
            return 1.5
        case .DD:
            return 1.0
        case .FF:
            return 0
        }
    }
    func sonuc( _ ilkKredi : Double) -> Double{
        grade * ilkKredi
    }
}
```

Then just change your `if let`

```
if let ilkNot = firstSectionGrade.text, let sectionGrade = SectionGrade(rawValue: ilkNot), let ilkKredi = ilkKredi {
    sonuc = sectionGrade.sonuc(ilkKredi)
} else{
    // Do something if firstSectionGrade.text == nil or
    // if ilkNot's value does not exist in SectionGrade or
    // ilkKredi is nil
}
```

Comment: @İbrahimBayram glad to help. If I answered your question do you mind accepting the answer? It is the green check mark above.